# Runtime Error: failed to instantiate new type: org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil$EnvironmentConfigCache

Tags: jboss, jbpm, jboss-eap-6, business-process-management

I am trying to install Redhat Jboss BPM suite 6 on EAP 6.
For this i referring the official installation guide. [Click here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6/pdf/Installation_Guide/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite-6-Installation_Guide-en-US.pdf)

Can anyone let me know the possible reasons.

During this i am  getting following exception ;

```
  14:02:57,025 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."business-central.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."business-central.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to instantiate new type: org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil$EnvironmentConfigCache
    at org.jboss.errai.common.rebind.CacheUtil.getCache(CacheUtil.java:46)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.getEnvironmentConfig(EnvUtil.java:299)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.isPortableType(EnvUtil.java:304)
    at org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints.processObserverMethod(CDIExtensionPoints.java:311)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:233)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:213)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:590)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:580)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessObserverMethodImpl.fire(ProcessObserverMethodImpl.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploy(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deployBeans(BeanDeployment.java:217)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:358)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to load environment extension: org.jboss.errai.bus.rebind.RpcTypesProvider
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.newEnvironmentConfig(EnvUtil.java:245)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.access$000(EnvUtil.java:56)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil$EnvironmentConfigCache.clear(EnvUtil.java:66)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil$EnvironmentConfigCache.<init>(EnvUtil.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.errai.common.rebind.CacheUtil.getCache(CacheUtil.java:42)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken
    at org.jboss.errai.codegen.meta.impl.java.JavaReflectionMethod.getParameters(JavaReflectionMethod.java:64)
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.rebind.RpcTypesProvider.provideTypesToExpose(RpcTypesProvider.java:46)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.newEnvironmentConfig(EnvUtil.java:235)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken from [Module "deployment.business-central.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 45 more

    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:83)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to instantiate new type: org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil$EnvironmentConfigCache
    at org.jboss.errai.common.rebind.CacheUtil.getCache(CacheUtil.java:46)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.getEnvironmentConfig(EnvUtil.java:299)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.isPortableType(EnvUtil.java:304)
    at org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints.processObserverMethod(CDIExtensionPoints.java:311)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:233)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:213)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:590)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:580)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessObserverMethodImpl.fire(ProcessObserverMethodImpl.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploy(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deployBeans(BeanDeployment.java:217)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:358)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to load environment extension: org.jboss.errai.bus.rebind.RpcTypesProvider
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.newEnvironmentConfig(EnvUtil.java:245)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.access$000(EnvUtil.java:56)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil$EnvironmentConfigCache.clear(EnvUtil.java:66)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil$EnvironmentConfigCache.<init>(EnvUtil.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.errai.common.rebind.CacheUtil.getCache(CacheUtil.java:42)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken
    at org.jboss.errai.codegen.meta.impl.java.JavaReflectionMethod.getParameters(JavaReflectionMethod.java:64)
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.rebind.RpcTypesProvider.provideTypesToExpose(RpcTypesProvider.java:46)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.newEnvironmentConfig(EnvUtil.java:235)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken from [Module "deployment.business-central.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 45 more

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessObserverMethodImpl.fire(ProcessObserverMethodImpl.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploy(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deployBeans(BeanDeployment.java:217)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:358)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    ... 5 more

14:02:59,684 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /dashbuilder
14:02:59,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) JBAS018559: Deployed "dashbuilder.war"
14:02:59,924 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) JBAS018559: Deployed "business-central.war"
14:02:59,925 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."business-central.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."business-central.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to instantiate new type: org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil$EnvironmentConfigCache
    at org.jboss.errai.common.rebind.CacheUtil.getCache(CacheUtil.java:46)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.getEnvironmentConfig(EnvUtil.java:299)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.isPortableType(EnvUtil.java:304)
    at org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints.processObserverMethod(CDIExtensionPoints.java:311)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:233)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:213)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:590)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:580)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessObserverMethodImpl.fire(ProcessObserverMethodImpl.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploy(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deployBeans(BeanDeployment.java:217)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:358)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to load environment extension: org.jboss.errai.bus.rebind.RpcTypesProvider
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.newEnvironmentConfig(EnvUtil.java:245)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.access$000(EnvUtil.java:56)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil$EnvironmentConfigCache.clear(EnvUtil.java:66)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil$EnvironmentConfigCache.<init>(EnvUtil.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.errai.common.rebind.CacheUtil.getCache(CacheUtil.java:42)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken
    at org.jboss.errai.codegen.meta.impl.java.JavaReflectionMethod.getParameters(JavaReflectionMethod.java:64)
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.rebind.RpcTypesProvider.provideTypesToExpose(RpcTypesProvider.java:46)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil.newEnvironmentConfig(EnvUtil.java:235)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken from [Module "deployment.business-central.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 45 more


14:03:00,326 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on localhost url
14:03:00,334 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss BPM Suite 6.0.0.GA (AS 7.1.2.Final-redhat-1) started (with errors) in 32668ms - Started 488 of 747 services (170 services failed or missing dependencies, 88 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing the eap artefact (and thus not the generic deployable) on a clean installation of eap 6.1.1 (note that this exact version is required)?

Maybe try a second time as well, to avoid corruption during download / unzip.

If thr issue persists, could you specify which OS and JRE you are using?

Comment: I am tried with fresh copy but its giving same exception.I am working on window 7 wiht jre7

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I figure out the answer.

Use Google **Guava version 13.0.1** instead of any other.

As i was using EAP 6.0.0 that why by default i have Google Guava version 11.0.1.

Replace Guava version 13.0.1 jar in `modules/com/google/guava/main/`* and edit the module.xml file accordingly